# Listbox search filter in delphi

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-xe4

Here I came across a problem while I am trying to search filter in a listbox. Actually I want to select all the items matched with respect to the text in the `TEdit` control. If the multiple items are matched, it should select multiple items.

By the way I have already selected `multiselect` property to True.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute  then
    for I := 0 to OpenDialog1.Files.Count - 1 do
       ListBox1.Items.Add(ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.Files.Strings[i]));
end;
```

Search filter code:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    ListBox1.Selected[i] := False;

  for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
     if ListBox1.Items.Strings[i].Contains(Edit1.Text) then
        ListBox1.Selected[i] := True;
end;
```

This code works when great but the problem is when I cannot search ignoring the cases. Means the search is case sensitive and I need to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Usually languages have an option to convert all text to the desired case. If you do so both for the query search and for the text where it search it would be case insensitive. (I don't know delphy, so I cannot say the exact function, but look to some tutorial or the documentation)

Comment: [`This way`](http://pastebin.com/6mSEigdk). @Llopis, or there can be a function to perform case insensitive search of a string. Delphi has the [`ContainsText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsText) function for that.

Comment: @TLama: Your code worked; I need to replace System.StrUtils in the uses instead of System.StrUtils.ContainsText since it was showing error that the System.StrUtils.ContainsText.dcu doesn't existed.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved using the code posted by TLama. Thanks to him.

Here is the code to be modified:

```
uses
  System.StrUtils;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      ListBox1.Selected[I] := ContainsText(ListBox1.Items[I], Edit1.Text);
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```